# Why is not the projectile going toward the target?

Tags: rotation, movement, unreal-4, projectile-physics

I have a project where I can shoot (with a simple projectile).

**Character Blueprint (generate projectile):**

[image]

However I would like to be able to make the projectile go towards a specific target.

**Projectile Blueprint (target definition):**

[image]

And I think that with the code below I would achieve the expected effect.

**Projectile Blueprint (change projectile rotation):**

[image]

**Some links that helped me get here (I may have let something pass):**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyNzsbTpGqg

https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/48896-homing-missile?77586-Homing-missile=

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/239188/rinterp-to-doesnt-slowly-change-character-rotation.html

I do not know what I'm doing wrong (based on the links above).

*The projectile walks straight and visibly I see no change in its trajectory.*

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just very small, since you set it to rotate in 20 seconds?

Comment: @Bálint I chose this value (20), based on the response of that link: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/239188/rinterp-to-doesnt-slowly-change-character-rotation.html

Comment: @Bálint I changed the value from 20 to 1, and nothing has changed.

Comment: @Bálint I changed the format of the projectile, and now I realize the change of its rotation. It seems that the higher the value, the faster the rotation changes.

Comment: But the projectile still does not go towards the target, it just points (it is facing).